# Scope of function called after deffered resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I have a function that need to wait for another function to be done before it can be called so I try to use `jquery deferred`. So for example:

```
firstFunction().done(secondFunction)
```

But `secondFunction` has in its scope some usages of `this` keyword so when it is called via `done` it don't have access for proper `this` property. For more those functions are placed in different files. Is there a way to call `secondFunction` with proper `this` property?

Comment: some code would be nice - but `.bind` may be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can bind the function to the correct context.

For IE9 and up you can use native Javascript for this, namely [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
firstFunction().done(secondFunction.bind(this));
```

If for some reason you're supporting IE8 then you either need to polyfill it (there's a recipe for that on the mdn page linked above) or you can use [underscore's bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) which should be available since it's required by backbone.

```
firstFunction().done(_.bind(secondFunction, this));
```